# Warning: Illegal string offset '#access' in views_handler_field_field->set_items() line 862 views_handler_field_field.inc

Tags: views

I'm having an error that I can't find an answer for, and was wondering if someone out there can help.

The error i get is...

Warning: Illegal string offset '#access' in views_handler_field_field->set_items() (line 862 of .../sites/all/modules/views/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc)

I have created a view, that is showing a multiple value result of a photo gallery from 10 nodes of the same content type. Basically I have a content type for venues, and each venue can upload an unlimited number of photos for their venue. This view sits on one of the main national pages, and shows all photos from all venues.

Looking at line 862, the error is in the following bit of code

> ```
>   // field_view_field() adds an #access property to the render array that
>   // determines whether or not the current user is allowed to view the
>   // field in the context of the current entity. We need to respect this
>   // parameter when we pull out the children of the field array for
>   // rendering.
>   if (isset($render_array['#access'])) {
>     $items[$count]['rendered']['#access'] = $render_array['#access'];
>   }
> ```

Can anyone help me and shed a bit of light on this? It looks like a permissions problem if a user doesn't have access to the content, but my permissions are no different than they have been for the last 10 drupal sites I have built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I realised that as well as the error, I was also seeing a "1" appear after the grid items.

This bug is related to the Grid Field Display module, and the answer and patch can be found at https://drupal.org/node/2046435